# Strange Bash if/elif behavior

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the following script:

```
a=$1
b=$2

if [ ! a ]; then
    echo "a=$a"
elif [ b ]; then
    echo "b=$b"
fi
```

This is the four possible ways I can call it:

```
balter$ bash eliftest.sh true true
b=true
balter$ bash eliftest.sh true false
b=false
balter$ bash eliftest.sh false true
b=true
balter$ bash eliftest.sh false false
b=false
```

I would have expected:

```
b=true # !a evaluates to false but b is true
<nothing> # !a evaluates to false and b is also false
a=false # !a evaluates to true and if short circuits 
a=false # !a evaluates to true and if short circuits
```

I clearly don't understand bash elif statements. Can someone enlighten me?

Also, one the interwebs, bash scripting tutorials sometimes use `[[...]]` but mostly `[...]`. I see a lot of SO commenters saying that you should use `[[...]]`. Is there a rule of thumb for when one is better than the other?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good point about the double quoting. I see how not doing it could mess things up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are making two mistakes:

1. you want to use the variable `a`, and not the character "a"; so use `$a`.
2. Since bash doesn't know booleans, you might just check if the value is "true".

So you want something like this:

```
if [ "$a" = "true" ]; then
    echo "a=$a"
elif [ "$b" = "true" ]; then
    echo "b=$b"
fi
```

I implemented two more recommendations:

- always put variables between quotes; to avoid errors when they are empty ("$a" instead of $a)
- use only one = sign for portability (as suggested by @tripleee)

**some more detaills**

bash doesn't know boolean values. Your test:

```
if [ ! a ];
```

will always fail since you ask bash: is the character "a" empty? Which is the same as:

```
if [ "" = "a" ]
```

suppose you did use `$a` (the variable):

```
if [  ! $a ]
```

this would still always be false; since this is equivalent to:

```
if [ "" = "$a" ]
```

which will never be true whether a=true or a=false (since a is never an empty string)

Comment: Indeed, your example works precisely as expected. Thanks.

Comment: @abalter I added an important remark about the variable expansion; consider using "$a" instead of $a; that will prevent you from future bugs...

Comment: For portability, you should use a single equals sign with `[`

Comment: @tripleee thanks, I edited my answer. Out of curiosity; in which case would the == lead to problems?

Comment: It will be a syntax error when your `sh` is `dash`, for example, I believe. The OP is explicitly using `bash` but making the answer portable to POSIX is useful regardless.

Comment: in bash 5, at least this works if $a ; then ... The lack of quotes and the space are nec.

Answer (score -1):

Avoid the brackets. Try this:

```
a=$1
b=$2
if ! $a 
then
    echo "a=$a"
elif $b 
then
    echo "b=$b"
fi
```

Comment: You should still quote your variables.  This will attempt to run `$1` and `$2` as shell commands, which is probably fine per se -- but probably not what the OP wants -- as long as they are `true` or `false`; but that doesn't prevent a user from passing in e.g. `"rm -rf /"` as the first parameter.  (If you quoted `"$a"` properly then at least it would be a syntax error instead of a security problem.)

Comment: I should have quoted `a="$1"`, but for the invocation of `$a`, it depends on the intended behaviour, whether or not quoting is the right thing. Of course this is a contrieved example, because I think the OP *wanted* to play around with the commands true or false (and not with strings representing boolean values) - in this case, 1 or 0 would perhaps be a better choice. If you really want to run a command, you get of course all the security problems which also would bring you `$eval`, but this doesn't depend on quoting: Even if you invoke `"$a"`, someone can set a to the name of a rogue script.